# Can't get Wifi to work with Intel Wireless Card

Tags: drivers, wireless, intel, firmware

I'm definitely not a Linux pro, but I can give a run-down of what I've tried so far:

1. I've went to search for additional drivers, which didn't work.
2. Ran `apt-get upgrade`, which didn't work.
3. Installed a backport of the Intel Driver (iwlwifi 7265).
4. Installed several firmwares, thinking maybe I just didn't have the right one, none of which worked.

When I turn the wireless switch on it immediately goes back off.

Terminal output from various commands:

```
########## wireless info START ##########

Report from: 03 May 2016 21:04 EDT -0400

Booted last: 03 May 2016 00:00 EDT -0400

Script from: 27 Sep 2015 00:34 UTC +0000

##### release ###########################

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial

##### kernel ############################

Linux 4.4.0-21-generic #37-Ubuntu SMP Mon Apr 18 18:33:37 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Parameters: ro, quiet, splash, vt.handoff=7

##### desktop ###########################

Ubuntu

##### lspci #############################

02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 7265 [8086:095a] (rev 61)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Dual Band Wireless-AC 7265 [8086:5010]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi

03:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 15)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [103c:80cf]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169

##### lsusb #############################

Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 8087:0a2a Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0483:91d1 STMicroelectronics Sensor Hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 05c8:0379 Cheng Uei Precision Industry Co., Ltd (Foxlink) 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 046d:c077 Logitech, Inc. M105 Optical Mouse
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

##### PCMCIA card info ##################

##### rfkill ############################

1: acer-wireless: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
2: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
7: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

##### lsmod #############################

iwlmvm                294912  0
mac80211              643072  1 iwlmvm
hp_wmi                 16384  0
iwlwifi               208896  1 iwlmvm
acer_wmi               20480  0
sparse_keymap          16384  2 acer_wmi,hp_wmi
cfg80211              557056  3 iwlwifi,mac80211,iwlmvm
compat                 16384  4 cfg80211,iwlwifi,mac80211,iwlmvm
wmi                    20480  2 acer_wmi,hp_wmi
video                  40960  2 i915_bpo,acer_wmi

##### interfaces ########################

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

##### ifconfig ##########################

enp3s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <MAC 'enp3s0' [IF]>  
          inet addr:192.168.1.101  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::6f5c:e762:a2b0:f4a3/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:7073112 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:5031061 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:10486701490 (10.4 GB)  TX bytes:376384144 (376.3 MB)

wlp2s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <MAC 'wlp2s0' [IF]>  
          BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

##### iwconfig ##########################

enp3s0    no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

wlp2s0    IEEE 802.11abgn  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=0 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:on


##### route #############################

Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 enp3s0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 enp3s0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 enp3s0

##### resolv.conf #######################

nameserver 127.0.1.1
search foothills.net

##### network managers ##################

Installed:

    NetworkManager

Running:

root       728     1  0 May02 ?        00:00:01 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon

##### NetworkManager info ###############

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         enp3s0
GENERAL.TYPE:                           ethernet
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceEthernet
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         r8169
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 2.3LK-NAPI
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         <MAC 'enp3s0' [IF]>
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          100 (connected)
GENERAL.REASON:                         0 (No reason given)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.5/0000:03:00.0/net/enp3s0
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       enp3s0
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     Wired connection 1
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       35192bd8-e202-4029-ba60-f9b410bd6826
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/5
GENERAL.METERED:                        no (guessed)
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            yes
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     100 Mb/s
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
WIRED-PROPERTIES.CARRIER:               on
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Settings/{0}
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTIONS[1]:   35192bd8-e202-4029-ba60-f9b410bd6826 | Wired connection 1
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         192.168.1.101/24
IP4.GATEWAY:                            192.168.1.1
IP4.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = 169.254.0.0/16, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 1000
IP4.DNS[1]:                             192.225.240.82
IP4.DNS[2]:                             192.225.240.83
IP4.DOMAIN[1]:                          foothills.net
DHCP4.OPTION[1]:                        requested_subnet_mask = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[2]:                        requested_rfc3442_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[3]:                        subnet_mask = 255.255.255.0
DHCP4.OPTION[4]:                        domain_name_servers = 192.225.240.82 192.225.240.83
DHCP4.OPTION[5]:                        ip_address = 192.168.1.101
DHCP4.OPTION[6]:                        requested_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[7]:                        dhcp_server_identifier = 192.168.1.1
DHCP4.OPTION[8]:                        requested_time_offset = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[9]:                        broadcast_address = 192.168.1.255
DHCP4.OPTION[10]:                       requested_interface_mtu = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[11]:                       dhcp_rebinding_time = 75600
DHCP4.OPTION[12]:                       requested_domain_name_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[13]:                       dhcp_message_type = 5
DHCP4.OPTION[14]:                       requested_broadcast_address = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[15]:                       routers = 192.168.1.1
DHCP4.OPTION[16]:                       dhcp_renewal_time = 43200
DHCP4.OPTION[17]:                       requested_domain_name = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[18]:                       domain_name = foothills.net
DHCP4.OPTION[19]:                       requested_routers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[20]:                       expiry = 1462390757
DHCP4.OPTION[21]:                       host_name = travis-HP-ENVY-x360-m6-Convertible
DHCP4.OPTION[22]:                       requested_netbios_scope = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[23]:                       requested_wpad = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[24]:                       requested_ms_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[25]:                       requested_netbios_name_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[26]:                       network_number = 192.168.1.0
DHCP4.OPTION[27]:                       requested_domain_search = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[28]:                       next_server = 192.168.1.1
DHCP4.OPTION[29]:                       requested_ntp_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[30]:                       requested_host_name = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[31]:                       dhcp_lease_time = 86400
IP6.ADDRESS[1]:                         fe80::6f5c:e762:a2b0:f4a3/64
IP6.GATEWAY:                            

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         wlp2s0
GENERAL.TYPE:                           wifi
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceWifi
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         Intel Corporation
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        Wireless 7265 (Dual Band Wireless-AC 7265)
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         iwlwifi
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 4.4.0-21-generic
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               15.195093.0
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         <MAC 'wlp2s0' [IF]>
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          20 (unavailable)
GENERAL.REASON:                         0 (No reason given)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.4/0000:02:00.0/net/wlp2s0
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     --
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       --
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       --
GENERAL.METERED:                        unknown
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            no
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     unknown
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WEP:                    yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WPA:                    yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WPA2:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.TKIP:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.CCMP:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.AP:                     yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.ADHOC:                  yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.2GHZ:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.5GHZ:                   yes
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: 

SSID  BSSID  MODE  CHAN  FREQ  RATE  SIGNAL  BARS  SECURITY  ACTIVE  * 

##### NetworkManager.state ##############

[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true

##### NetworkManager.conf ###############

[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
dns=dnsmasq

[ifupdown]
managed=false

##### NetworkManager profiles ###########

##### iw reg get ########################

Region: America/New_York (based on set time zone)

country 00: DFS-UNSET
    (2402 - 2472 @ 40), (N/A, 20), (N/A)
    (2457 - 2482 @ 40), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-IR
    (2474 - 2494 @ 20), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-OFDM, NO-IR
    (5170 - 5250 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-IR
    (5250 - 5330 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (0 ms), DFS, NO-IR
    (5490 - 5730 @ 160), (N/A, 20), (0 ms), DFS, NO-IR
    (5735 - 5835 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-IR
    (57240 - 63720 @ 2160), (N/A, 0), (N/A)

##### iwlist channels ###################

enp3s0    no frequency information.

lo        no frequency information.

wlp2s0    32 channels in total; available frequencies :
          Channel 01 : 2.412 GHz
          Channel 02 : 2.417 GHz
          Channel 03 : 2.422 GHz
          Channel 04 : 2.427 GHz
          Channel 05 : 2.432 GHz
          Channel 06 : 2.437 GHz
          Channel 07 : 2.442 GHz
          Channel 08 : 2.447 GHz
          Channel 09 : 2.452 GHz
          Channel 10 : 2.457 GHz
          Channel 11 : 2.462 GHz
          Channel 12 : 2.467 GHz
          Channel 13 : 2.472 GHz
          Channel 36 : 5.18 GHz
          Channel 40 : 5.2 GHz
          Channel 44 : 5.22 GHz
          Channel 48 : 5.24 GHz
          Channel 52 : 5.26 GHz
          Channel 56 : 5.28 GHz
          Channel 60 : 5.3 GHz
          Channel 64 : 5.32 GHz
          Channel 100 : 5.5 GHz
          Channel 104 : 5.52 GHz
          Channel 108 : 5.54 GHz
          Channel 112 : 5.56 GHz
          Channel 116 : 5.58 GHz
          Channel 120 : 5.6 GHz
          Channel 124 : 5.62 GHz
          Channel 128 : 5.64 GHz
          Channel 132 : 5.66 GHz
          Channel 136 : 5.68 GHz
          Channel 140 : 5.7 GHz

##### iwlist scan #######################

enp3s0    Interface doesn't support scanning.

wlp2s0    Interface doesn't support scanning : Network is down

lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

##### module infos ######################

[iwlmvm]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.4.0-21-generic/updates/drivers/net/wireless/iwlwifi/mvm/iwlmvm.ko
version:        backported from Linux (v4.2.6-0-g1c02865) using backports v4.2.6-1-0-g90118c7
license:        GPL
author:         Copyright(c) 2003- 2015 Intel Corporation <ilw@linux.intel.com>
description:    The new Intel(R) wireless AGN driver for Linux
srcversion:     02754162E71EA56CF142DCD
depends:        iwlwifi,mac80211,compat,cfg80211
vermagic:       4.4.0-21-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
parm:           init_dbg:set to true to debug an ASSERT in INIT fw (default: false (bool)
parm:           power_scheme:power management scheme: 1-active, 2-balanced, 3-low power, default: 2 (int)
parm:           tfd_q_hang_detect:TFD queues hang detection (default: true (bool)

[mac80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.4.0-21-generic/updates/net/mac80211/mac80211.ko
license:        GPL
description:    IEEE 802.11 subsystem
version:        backported from Linux (v4.2.6-0-g1c02865) using backports v4.2.6-1-0-g90118c7
srcversion:     E76E2165EA4C6AB2329AA8B
depends:        cfg80211,compat
vermagic:       4.4.0-21-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
parm:           max_nullfunc_tries:Maximum nullfunc tx tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           max_probe_tries:Maximum probe tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           beacon_loss_count:Number of beacon intervals before we decide beacon was lost. (int)
parm:           probe_wait_ms:Maximum time(ms) to wait for probe response before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           ieee80211_default_rc_algo:Default rate control algorithm for mac80211 to use (charp)

[iwlwifi]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.4.0-21-generic/updates/drivers/net/wireless/iwlwifi/iwlwifi.ko
version:        backported from Linux (v4.2.6-0-g1c02865) using backports v4.2.6-1-0-g90118c7
license:        GPL
author:         Copyright(c) 2003- 2015 Intel Corporation <ilw@linux.intel.com>
description:    Intel(R) Wireless WiFi driver for Linux
firmware:       iwlwifi-100-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-1000-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-135-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-105-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-2030-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-2000-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-5150-2.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-5000-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6000g2b-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6000g2a-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6050-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6000-4.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-7265D-12.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-7265-12.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-3160-12.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-7260-12.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-8000-12.ucode
srcversion:     83024FD9DE1694977CC3029
depends:        compat,cfg80211
vermagic:       4.4.0-21-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
parm:           debug:debug output mask (uint)
parm:           swcrypto:using crypto in software (default 0 [hardware]) (int)
parm:           11n_disable:disable 11n functionality, bitmap: 1: full, 2: disable agg TX, 4: disable agg RX, 8 enable agg TX (uint)
parm:           amsdu_size_8K:enable 8K amsdu size (default 0) (int)
parm:           fw_restart:restart firmware in case of error (default true) (bool)
parm:           antenna_coupling:specify antenna coupling in dB (default: 0 dB) (int)
parm:           nvm_file:NVM file name (charp)
parm:           d0i3_disable:disable d0i3 functionality (default: Y) (bool)
parm:           lar_disable:disable LAR functionality (default: N) (bool)
parm:           uapsd_disable:disable U-APSD functionality (default: Y) (bool)
parm:           bt_coex_active:enable wifi/bt co-exist (default: enable) (bool)
parm:           led_mode:0=system default, 1=On(RF On)/Off(RF Off), 2=blinking, 3=Off (default: 0) (int)
parm:           power_save:enable WiFi power management (default: disable) (bool)
parm:           power_level:default power save level (range from 1 - 5, default: 1) (int)
parm:           fw_monitor:firmware monitor - to debug FW (default: false - needs lots of memory) (bool)

[cfg80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.4.0-21-generic/updates/net/wireless/cfg80211.ko
version:        backported from Linux (v4.2.6-0-g1c02865) using backports v4.2.6-1-0-g90118c7
description:    wireless configuration support
license:        GPL
author:         Johannes Berg
srcversion:     75463EDBD0CFDDF127DF5B4
depends:        compat
vermagic:       4.4.0-21-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
parm:           ieee80211_regdom:IEEE 802.11 regulatory domain code (charp)
parm:           cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz:Disable 40MHz support in the 2.4GHz band (bool)

##### module parameters #################

[iwlmvm]
init_dbg: N
power_scheme: 2
tfd_q_hang_detect: Y

[mac80211]
beacon_loss_count: 7
max_nullfunc_tries: 2
max_probe_tries: 5
probe_wait_ms: 500

[iwlwifi]
11n_disable: 0
amsdu_size_8K: 0
antenna_coupling: 0
bt_coex_active: Y
d0i3_disable: Y
debug: 0
fw_monitor: N
fw_restart: Y
lar_disable: N
led_mode: 0
nvm_file: (null)
power_level: 0
power_save: N
swcrypto: 0
uapsd_disable: Y

[cfg80211]
cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz: N
ieee80211_regdom: 00

##### /etc/modules ######################

##### modprobe options ##################

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf]
blacklist ath_pci

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-bcm43.conf]
blacklist b43
blacklist b43legacy
blacklist ssb
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist brcm80211
blacklist brcmfmac
blacklist brcmsmac
blacklist bcma

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf]
blacklist evbug
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd
blacklist eepro100
blacklist de4x5
blacklist eth1394
blacklist snd_intel8x0m
blacklist snd_aw2
blacklist i2c_i801
blacklist prism54
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist garmin_gps
blacklist asus_acpi
blacklist snd_pcsp
blacklist pcspkr
blacklist amd76x_edac

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rare-network.conf]
alias net-pf-3 off
alias net-pf-6 off
alias net-pf-9 off
alias net-pf-11 off
alias net-pf-12 off
alias net-pf-19 off
alias net-pf-21 off
alias net-pf-36 off

[/etc/modprobe.d/broadcom-sta-common.conf]
blacklist b43
blacklist b43legacy
blacklist b44
blacklist bcma
blacklist brcm80211
blacklist brcmsmac
blacklist ssb
install wl /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install wl $CMDLINE_OPTS

[/etc/modprobe.d/broadcom-sta-dkms.conf]
blacklist b43
blacklist b43legacy
blacklist b44
blacklist bcma
blacklist brcm80211
blacklist brcmsmac
blacklist ssb

[/etc/modprobe.d/intel-microcode-blacklist.conf]
blacklist microcode

[/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf]
remove iwlwifi \
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211

[/etc/modprobe.d/mlx4.conf]
softdep mlx4_core post: mlx4_en

##### rc.local ##########################

exit 0

##### pm-utils ##########################

##### udev rules ########################

grep: /etc/udev/rules.d/*net*.rules: No such file or directory

##### dmesg #############################

[46468.216833] wl: disagrees about version of symbol wiphy_register
[46468.216836] wl: Unknown symbol wiphy_register (err -22)
[46468.216995] wl: disagrees about version of symbol wiphy_unregister
[46468.216998] wl: Unknown symbol wiphy_unregister (err -22)
[46468.217047] wl: disagrees about version of symbol __ieee80211_get_channel
[46468.217050] wl: Unknown symbol __ieee80211_get_channel (err -22)
[46468.217215] wl: disagrees about version of symbol wiphy_free
[46468.217218] wl: Unknown symbol wiphy_free (err -22)
[46733.455836] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled (repeated 4 times)
[46733.549903] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp2s0: link is not ready
[46834.598589] wl: disagrees about version of symbol wiphy_new_nm
[46834.598590] wl: Unknown symbol wiphy_new_nm (err -22)
[46834.598601] wl: disagrees about version of symbol wiphy_register
[46834.598602] wl: Unknown symbol wiphy_register (err -22)
[46834.598670] wl: disagrees about version of symbol wiphy_unregister
[46834.598671] wl: Unknown symbol wiphy_unregister (err -22)
[46834.598691] wl: disagrees about version of symbol __ieee80211_get_channel
[46834.598693] wl: Unknown symbol __ieee80211_get_channel (err -22)
[46834.598758] wl: disagrees about version of symbol wiphy_free
[46834.598759] wl: Unknown symbol wiphy_free (err -22)
[46885.094245] wl: disagrees about version of symbol wiphy_new_nm
[46885.094246] wl: Unknown symbol wiphy_new_nm (err -22)
[46885.094256] wl: disagrees about version of symbol wiphy_register
[46885.094257] wl: Unknown symbol wiphy_register (err -22)
[46885.094316] wl: disagrees about version of symbol wiphy_unregister
[46885.094317] wl: Unknown symbol wiphy_unregister (err -22)
[46885.094335] wl: disagrees about version of symbol __ieee80211_get_channel
[46885.094336] wl: Unknown symbol __ieee80211_get_channel (err -22)
[46885.094395] wl: disagrees about version of symbol wiphy_free
[46885.094396] wl: Unknown symbol wiphy_free (err -22)
[47552.655303] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled (repeated 4 times)
[47552.739928] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp2s0: link is not ready (repeated 2 times)

########## wireless info END ############
```

I'm not a terminal pro, so with any suggestions terminal specifics would be fantastic.

Comment: Let's first confirm your  device. Please edit your question to include the result of: `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A2` Welcome to askubuntu.

Comment: Please [run the network diagnostics](//askubuntu.com/a/425205/175814) and [edit] your question to include a link to the result.

Comment: You are aware that you can post your update as an answer to your own question?  You might want to do so and later accept it so the question gets marked as solved. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE:
I found the fix to this problem.
For those who have a similar problem:
access the terminal with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

run:

```
sudo nano /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
add blacklist acer_wmi as a new line at the bottom of this file. 




then reboot after saving with ctrl+O and enter!.
```

This blacklists acer_wmi, which seems to fix the issues I was having.

cheers!

Answer (score 0):

It works in my case after I disable the Wireless Card in the BIOS setup, boot the OS and shut it down, then enable the Wireless Card in the BIOS.